# How to Validate Header in API Gateway in Cloudformation?

Tags: amazon-web-services, http-headers, aws-cloudformation

I've read through quite a few AWS docs and couldn't find one that describes the validation of http request header in Cloudformation. Can anyone help? I just need to check if the "referer" header exist.

Comment: What's the problem you are trying to solve?
Are you referring to the API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add header validation by using the [`RequestParameters`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-apigateway-method.html#cfn-apigateway-method-requestparameters) property to your `AWS::ApiGateway::Method` Cloudformation resource. The documentation is not super clear on how to use it, but the syntax should be something like

```
      RequestParameters:
        method.request.header.referer: true
```

See [this blog post](https://cjohansen.no/aws-apigw-proxy-cloudformation/) for a working example of using Cloudformation to create API resources. Notice that the example validates a path variable instead of a header, but the syntax will be the same.

You might also need to add a [`AWS::ApiGateway::RequestValidator`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-apigateway-requestvalidator.html) resource to your Cloudformation template to enforce the validation, but I suspect that is what the boolean in the `RequestParameters` map is for, you will have to do some experimentation on that.